# operations puzzle

Tags: puzzle

> Obtain the number 1500 by using the operations $×, +, -, ÷$ on the numbers $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,$ in that order. Brackets are allowed, but you cannot join digits to form multi-digit numbers: for example, you may not write $1$ next to $2$ and call this $12$.

A possible solution is: $(1+2+3+4)×5×(6+7+8+9)$

Another solution: $(1÷(2×3))(4×5)(6×7+8)(9)$

My question: Is there a way to guess/know how many solutions are there?

Comment: Can you use the computer brute-force?

Comment: @kotomord What do you mean by "the computer brute-force". I think you simply mean to run a program to check every order? Actually, I want to solve this by hand.

Comment: Program method has a problem -  how to union (1 +2 +3), 1 + (2+3) and (1+2) +3?

Comment: @kotomord I'm not familiar with programming. Whatever, it's not the solving way I'm looking for, but it may help to check someone's answer. I think it has 7-9 solutions. (: